# VBA how to change value in a visible cell if two criteria is met

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I need to change the level of each student if they passed two criteria. I wish to change the value inside the level column, but if it's not possible maybe put the changes next to the column is still accepted.

| NIP | Name | Math Score | English Score | Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Ariana | 75 | 75 | Level 1 |
| 1235 | Brian | 80 | 85 | Level 2 |
| 1236 | Charlie | 75 |  | Level 3 |

Criteria 1 = Math Score; Criteria 2 = English Score

If  both criteria cells is filled with values (regardless what's the score), then the student will be promoted to the next level.

Example Ariana will be Level 2 and Brian will be Level 3

While, Charlie's "D" column is not a subject to changes because criteria 1 and 2 are not met.

note: I want the code to apply on visible cells only because I'll use filter on the level column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `SpecialCells()` method of `Range` object to filter visible and not empty cells in cascade

you should then use a lot of nested If ... Then ... and check if there are any visible rows with not empty cells in columns 3 and 4

but the conscious use of `On Error Resume Next` statement could simplify the matter

```
Sub UpDateLevel()
    With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
            On Error Resume Next
                Dim cel As Range
                    For Each cel In Intersect(.Columns(3).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow, _
                                              .Columns(4).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants))
                        With cel.Offset(, 1)
                            .Value = Split(.Value, " ")(0) & " " & Split(.Value, " ")(1) + 1
                        End With
                    Next
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: magnificently works! But I'm wondering what if the column level is on column E (two columns apart from column 4). Which code I should change?

Comment: currently the code is considering columns C and D for criteria and acts on column E for the Level.
this latter is reached  with "cel.Offset(, 1)" as being one column to the right of column D.
hence if you need F as the Level column, then just change "cel.Offset(, 1)" to "cel.Offset(, 2)", i.e. shift two columns right of column D

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table is in sheet 1 range as of A1:

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub update()
        Dim arr, r As Long, arr2() As String
        arr = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        
        For r = 2 To UBound(arr)
            If Not IsEmpty(arr(r, 3)) And Not IsEmpty(arr(r, 4)) Then
                arr2 = Split(arr(r, 5), " ", -1, vbTextCompare)
                arr(r, 5) = arr2(0) & " " & arr2(1) + 1
            End If
        Next r
        
        Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion = arr
    End Sub
```

You can add a button or add an onsheetchange event to launch the code.

Comment: it works! but, the code cannot work on the filtered level. How can I change the code to apply on visible cells only?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little brut force but it works.

[image]

Comment: and max 9 levels :)